# TeamCity isn't accepting an array as parameter value

Tags: python, teamcity

I have a python script which generates a list of host names that I need to use in another step. The list I am trying to pass in is standard array format:

```
['12R214PS93A8G', '12R214WB93A8G', '12R214DS93A8G', '12R214AG93A8G']
```

The problem is when I try to set the value of the parameter:

```
##teamcity[setParameter name='env.HOSTNAMES' value='['12R214PS93A8G', '12R214WB93A8G', '12R214DS93A8G', '12R214AG93A8G']'
```

I get the following error:

```
Property value not found
Valid property list format is (name( )*=( )*'escaped_value'( )*)* where escape symbol is "|"**strong text**
']
```

The workaround is I can pass all host name smashed together as a single string and parse it out later but it would be great if I could just send in an array. I tried setting the value with double quotes because I can't change the fact that the array delimiter is a single quote (or can I?) but I just received an error saying that the value has to start with a single quote.

Answer (score 4):

[TeamCity requires you to escape](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ServiceMessages) single quotes, new lines, pipes and square brackets inside the value attribute, most by just prefixing with a pipe.

Using your example (the first line becomes the second):

```
##teamcity[setParameter name='env.HOSTNAMES' value='['12R214PS93A8G', '12R214WB93A8G', '12R214DS93A8G', '12R214AG93A8G']'

##teamcity[setParameter name='env.HOSTNAMES' value='[|'12R214PS93A8G|', |'12R214WB93A8G|', |'12R214DS93A8G|', |'12R214AG93A8G|'|]']
```